# HITLayoutParameters How to Fill up

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, slice, mechanicalturk

Here's how I send a request to mturk via Go:

```
resp_create, err := svc.CreateHIT(&mturk.CreateHITInput{
    Title: aws.String("Title Sample"),
    Reward:   aws.String("1"),
    Description:  aws.String("Sample Desc"),
    HITLayoutId: aws.String("33XXXXXXXXXXXX"),
    HITLayoutParameters: []mturk.HITLayoutParameter{"image_url", "https://nationalinterest.org/sites/default/files/styles/desktop__1260_/public/main_images/fdgtrtttr.jpg?itok=RnfT8ENG"},
    AssignmentDurationInSeconds: aws.Int64(604800),
    LifetimeInSeconds: aws.Int64(604800),
    Keywords:aws.String("image, identification"),
})
```

Which for some reason is failing, how do I fill `HITLayoutParameters` correctly, that needs a `[]mturk.HITLayoutParameter` parameter for my image. I tried a few attempts to basic slice and etc. but nothing works so far.

To produce you would have to [create a hit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_CreateHITOperation.html) then during HIT creation you have to put a layout parameter where youd have to insert the `image_url` and the url itself. The key for this is [HITLayoutParameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/mturk/#HITLayoutParameter) which accepts list type.

Answer (score 0):

Here was how to do it after a few trial and errors:

```
resp_create, err := svc.CreateHIT(&mturk.CreateHITInput{
    Title: aws.String("Title Sample"),
    Reward:   aws.String("1"),
    Description:  aws.String("Sample Desc"),
    HITLayoutId: aws.String("35EXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"),
    HITLayoutParameters: []*mturk.HITLayoutParameter{

        { Name: aws.String("image_url"), Value: aws.String("https://nationalinterest.org/sites/default/files/styles/desktop__1260_/public/main_images/fdgtrtttr.jpg?itok=RnfT8ENG")},

    },
    AssignmentDurationInSeconds: aws.Int64(604800),
    LifetimeInSeconds: aws.Int64(604800),
    Keywords:aws.String("image, identification"),
})
```